# Where is php.ini-development on Ubuntu LAMP?

Tags: php5, ubuntu-10.04, lamp

On my development machine I run Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS. Following [the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP), I used the following command to install Apache, MySQL and **PHP** in one go:

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

Now that I'm testing my PHP scripts, I want to enable "developer mode", if there is one, to enable error reporting and logging. I have read reference to files `php.ini-production` and `php.ini-development` that apparently come with some versions of PHP 5, but not the one I have installed.

All I have is `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. This configuration does not echo errors or warnings, which makes my scripts hard to debug. I guess I can edit the configuration by hand, but I'd rather just be able to drop in a replacement if that's possible.

So what I'm looking for is an easy way to switch between development and production environments for PHP!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**php.ini-development** and **php.ini-production**, which come with the PHP 5.3 package, are really just examples of recommended settings. You should review the settings and make sure that they apply to your use and copy them to the regular **php.ini** file location. On my Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS (lucid) server, here’s where I find mine:

```
# locate php.ini-development
/usr/share/doc/php5-common/examples/php.ini-development
```

The alternative example, **php.ini-production**, is in the same directory.

Answer (score 9):

php.ini-development file for php7 on ubuntu 16.04 is located in

```
/usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-development
```

So you can do the following: make backup copy of your current php.ini:

```
$ sudo mv /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini.back
```

then copy production ini file:

```
$ sudo cp /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-development /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

and restart the server:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This was the right place to look in php 8 as well. `/usr/lib/php/8.0/`